# Unable to connect to host via ssh

Tags: ssh

I have problem connecting to host via ssh. It prompts me this error :

```
debianbox@debian:~$ssh cdcharles@hephaistos.rsr.lip6.fr
ssh_exchange_identification : Connection closed by remote host
```

The problem is that I used to connect to that machine before with the same account, but now I don't know what happen I just get this error. I try to warn the admin but he says that everything works fine. Can somebody tells me what is the problem?

Comment: is the ssh server running something like [denyhosts](http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/)?  Have you tried SSH'ing in from a different IP?

Comment: No I did not try.

Comment: If there is something like `denyhosts` running, it will temporarily (or permanently, depending on configuration) blacklist your IP (for incoming SSH), by putting an entry in `/etc/hosts.deny`  Your output above is consistent with this scenario.  Try to confirm this by SSH'ing to that box from another (external) IP.  If you don't have more than one external IP, SSH into another offsite box then SSH into the box in question.

Comment: Run `ssh -vvv …` and post the output, so we know at what point the remote host closes the connection.

Comment: Probably you are really running denyhost or something similar, because the first time I tried to log I could type a password. After typing wrong passwords voluntarily, I could not see the same login message. The same issue appears with different IPs.

Comment: Hi, I have finally resolve my problem. As @chad said, I connect to another host and then reconnects to the site host. Thanks for your help

Comment: To solve the problem (if `denyhosts` was running on the server), have the server admin add an entry to `hosts.allow` for your IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned in the comments that connecting from other addresses works, so most likely you have something like [denyhosts](http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/) running. Denyhosts detects failed SSH attempts and (if there are too many) blocks connections from that address. Check your `/etc/hosts.deny` file to see if your machine's IP address is in there, and remove it if so. You can add it to `/etc/hosts.allow` if you like, so it will always be able to connect even if Denyhosts blocks it again

<sub>(Adapted from several comments on the question)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

It means that the initial SSH handshake isn't completing properly. There could be several reasons for this, but in my experience it was because the SSH listening service has crashed. The socket opens, but it can't talk SSH inside the socket.

What kind of device are you connecting to? Do you have a way to restart SSH without logging in via SSH?